# How to find the latitude and longitude from the given residential address?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

I have a problem in finding out the latitude and longitude coordinates from any given residential address in windows phone 7.I have tried it many times but cannot find the answer. How to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), just give it an address and it will return the full location information (country, locality, postal code, latitude & longitude, etc.)

Comment: Free use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day

Comment: Yes, but since this service doesn't require any registration or access key, I assume that is 2500 per IP address per day! I don't think that will be an issue to anyone use it on the phone! ;)

Comment: From the official : _the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited._

Comment: @Cybermaxs, you are absolutely correct! I do think that is a new rule for the service, as I can't remember reading it a few months ago when I last used it in my own apps...

Answer (score 2):

You should use an external API to get latitude and longitude coordinates for a location by specifying values such as a locality, postal code, and street address. This require a data connection.

There are many available services for this.

You can try [Bing Maps Search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx)

Comment: Bing maps API is free for mobile.